# JPA specification for NoSQL databases

Tags: jpa, nosql

I have just heard about that JPA specification is now available and usable for nosql databases. My question here is, is it the same as the one which we are used to use with relational databases ? because there are many differences between relational and nosql database especially when we talk about transaction which is not the same whatsoever. Did oracle release a new specification that encompasses new changes for nosql databases ?

regards

Comment: JPA is about object-relational mapping, so it can't be about No SQL databases.  You'll have to find another spec.

Comment: There is Hibernate OGM which is one of the JPA implementation for nosql database.

Comment: Hibernate ORM came before JPA; I'm guessing this one was born without a spec.  I don't use either one; I think both are a waste of time and only add unnecessary dependencies and complexity.  They're for people who don't know SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JPA` is defined totally for RDBMS datastores. See Oracles specification.

There are a few of the well known `JPA` implementations that have extended their support for JPA to also allow *some* non-RDBMS datastores to be used with the same API (the original one that did this was [DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org), but [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org) and EclipseLink have copied this since). While you can use the same API for persistence, you have to be aware that you make some compromises since the query language in particular is not always suited to non-RDBMS datastores. There are no plans (that I know of) to have a `JPA` spec for non-RDBMS.

There **is** a `JDO` (`Java Data Objects`) persistence spec that applies to RDBMS and non-RDBMS, and the JDO API is more suited to many different types of datastores.

Comment: You mean that JPA is only for RDBMS datastore, but there is a lot of discussions and talks about JPA for nosql db, and there is an Hibernate version for nosql db called Hobernate Object/Grid Mapper, what do u think about that ?  As for the JPA specification,  is there any new version for nosql db ?

Comment: I already said that JPA is for RDBMS only, so that sentence tells you there is no new version for non-RDBMS. Updated answer to mention JDO API. This site is not for "what do you think about" type questions

Comment: Why do they use it for nosql db then ? As you say that is for RDBMS db and there is no new version for nosql db ?

Comment: Why? They allow the *option* for users to use it for non-RDBMS. It's not illegal for vendors to allow extra options that are beyond the spec

Comment: And how is it possible to use JPA (meant to be used for RDBMS) for nosql db given that there is a lot of differences between RDBMS and NoSql DBMS. How does this work for that ?

Comment: Would have thought that was obvious. You have methods called "em.persist", "em.remove" which persist and remove objects; hardly controversial. As already said, the compromises are in the query language in particular.